# windows phone emulator IE version

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone, windows-phone-7-emulator

I have downloaded Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Updated version.

I want to know the IE version it uses.

Also wanted to know how to get the Emulator for windows phone 7.5 which uses IE9 or how can I get IE9 installed on this emulator.

Comment: I found the answer my self.

I simply visited this website http://html5test.com/ and it showed me the IE version which is 9.

Hope this question helps some else.

Answer (score 0):

Just point the browser at www.WhatBrowser.org and read the version of the page. It is almost certainly going to be IE Mobile 9.

Answer (score 0):

click F12 on Internet explorer to activate the debuger find the emulator mode and choose your version